# SQL COUNT giving same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this...

```
 Attendance_ID   person_ID  Meeting_ID  date
---------------  ---------  ----------  ----------
             23         25         123  2013-03-21
             24         25         456  2013-03-21
             25         25         789  2013-03-21
             26         13         147  2013-03-21
             27         25         123  2013-03-22
             28         82         147  2013-03-22
             29         82         456  2013-03-22
             30         13         147  2013-03-23
             31         25         456  2013-03-23
             32         13         456  2013-03-24
             33         25         456  2013-03-28
```

The goal is to print out all the the times a employee has missed one or more meetings during the day. I have tried the following query but it gives me the same result of 2 for all dates...

```
SELECT
    replace(replace(dayname(date),"Saturday", "Weekend"),"Sunday", "Weekend") AS day,
    count(distinct personID) AS absences
from
    AttendanceRecord
GROUP BY
    day;
```

where it should be...

```
Friday   2
Thursday 3
Weekend  3
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be welcome as my SQL skills are a bit rusty. Thanks!

This is MySQL, and the table above is the dates of absences. So if the emplyee missed meeting 123, they would show up on this table. The query is to see the number of employees who missed a meeting on that day.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: From your sample data, how can we tell that an employee missed a meeting? It would help if you could explain the logic and show us your expected result.

Comment: Why do you think `2, 2, 2` is incorrect? There are 2 `personId` that missed on Thursday (13, 25), 2 that missed Friday (25,82), and 2 weekend (13, 25). What is incorrect there? I'm guessing there is an issue with your sample data or you aren't expecting `distinct personID`.

Comment: @Chris Sloan are you trying to find the absences (1) per person,  (2) per day, or (3) per person per day (Ex: How many meetings person #25 missed on friday)?

Comment: I'm with dvo here. The counts seem correct. Two absent persons for the two weekdays each and two at the weekend. So please explain what makes you think this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
count(distinct personID) AS absences
```

should be

```
count(distinct employeeID) AS absences
```

because if you see your example data you have:

```
Employee ID person ID Meeting ID date
----------- --------- ---------- ----------
         23        25        123 2013-03-21
         24        25        456 2013-03-21
         25        25        789 2013-03-21
```

where these 3 different Employees have the same Person ID

---

Either that, or you're already getting the correct values; there are 10 different EmployeeID but there are fewer than that PersonID

---

If you still want to count repeated personIDs, then change

```
count(distinct personID) AS absences
```

to

```
count(personID) AS absences
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be, as long as every meeting was attended by at least one person.

```
WITH ALL_MEETING_EMPLOYEE_COMBOS AS
         ( SELECT EmployeeID, 
                  Meeting_ID,
                  date
             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
                          Employee_ID
                     FROM Attendance_Record
                  )
            CROSS JOIN 
                  ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                           meeting_id,
                           date
                      FROM attendance_record
                  )
   )
SELECT Employee_ID,
       Date,
       COUNT(1) AS MissedOnThisDayCount
  FROM ALL_MEETING_EMPLOYEE_COMBOS T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM ATTENDANCE_RECORD AR
            WHERE T1.employee_id = AR.employee_id
              AND T1.meeting_id = AR.meeting_id
         )

GROUP BY employee_id, date
```